# Jquery addClass Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I have tried severally and it's still not working. Here is my code.

I want `<p>content</P>` content to disappear after 3seconds

```
$loginmessage = "<br /><p class='alert alert-danger'>Login Fail</p>";
<div id="alertarea" class="text-center"><?php if(isset($loginmessage)) echo $loginmessage ?></div>

$("document").ready(function(){
    function hideWithTime(){
        if($("div#alertarea p").html != ""){
            $(this).addClass('hideit');
        }
    }
    // setTimeout(hideWithTime(), 2000);
    hideWithTime();
});
```

Comment: Because `this` doesn't defined in your code. You should use `$("div#alertarea p")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Its `html()` - a function not `html` - a property

Cache your element, `this` doesn't refer to `$("div#alertarea > p")`

```
$("document").ready(function(){
       var element = $("div#alertarea > p");
        function hideWithTime(){
            if(element.html() != ""){
               element.addClass('hideit');//ps bootstrap has a hide class
            }
        }

         setTimeout(hideWithTime, 2000); 
    });`
```

Comment: Thank you. why is $(this) not working? I have used ($("div#alertarea > p") and it's somehow trying to work. It disappear without even showing at all. I want the P to disappear after 3secs

Comment: for `this` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

If the child of the div is just a `p` tag, your code finds always no html. better do:

```
function hideWithTime(){
    if($("div#alertarea").html() != ""){
            $("div#alertarea>p").addClass('hideit');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support.. This worked with your suggestion

`setTimeout (function(){
    if($("div#alertarea").html() != ""){
            $("div#alertarea>p").addClass('hideit');
        }
  }, 5000);`